# Getting Started With Rails tutorial delete function not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've followed [the tutorial up to 5.13](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) and everything works except for two aspects of the blog:

1. the delete function navigates to the page I want to delete instead of deleting it.
2. In my CMD I get a bunch of render errors pertaining to a routing_error within the layout folder, but I'm not sure if that is a problem that will be addressed later in the tutorial or not.

The meat of my question relates to the non-function of the delete link

index.html.erb

```
    <h1>My Notes</h1>
 <%= link_to 'New Note', new_article_path %>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Note Entry Title</th>
    <th>Preview</th>
    <th colspan="3"></th>
  </tr>

  <% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= article.title %></td>
      <td><%= article.text %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', article_path(article) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', article_path(article),
              method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>  #<<< This is the delete code

    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

articles_controller.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    def index
    @articles = Article.all
    end

    def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
    @article = Article.new
    end

    def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def create
    #render plain: params[:article].inspect
    #@article = Article.new(params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)) 
        @article = Article.new(article_params)

        if @article.save
            redirect_to @article
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
        if @article.update(article_params)
            redirect_to @article
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end
    def destroy #<<< This is the destroy method
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
        @article.destroy

        redirect_to articles_path
    end
    private
        def article_params
            params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
    end
end
```

I guess I'm simply not sure how to resolve this issue given I've followed the tutorial verbatim and spent the last half week trying to resolve this problem only to be led down rabbit holes by other posts that either don't pertain to the issue or are not ample fixes. Perhaps I missed a typo, but I've combed the code multiple times already (Note I am a Ruby beginner so this stuff is very new to me).

Below is an image of the error message I am getting each time I click on any link on the page (the show and edit/save buttons work along with creating new pages, but delete just navigates the page.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeeCB.png

UPDATE 4/26/2017 - 1:00 PM

routes.rb file code:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  #get 'welcome/index' <- commented this out from earlier step in tutorial

  resources :articles 
  root 'welcome#index'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

CMD ERROR CODE - This is a supplement to the screenshot provided above

```
C:\Users\Nick\blog>rails server
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.2 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
*** SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGHUP not implemented, signal based logs reopening unavailable!
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.8.2 (ruby 2.3.3-p222), codename: Sassy Salamander
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
Started GET "/articles" for ::1 at 2017-04-26 10:47:37 -0400
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
  Rendering articles/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Article Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"
  Rendered articles/index.html.erb within layouts/application (16.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 275ms (Views: 241.1ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)


Started GET "/stylesheets/default.css" for ::1 at 2017-04-26 10:47:50 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/default.css"):
Started GET "/javascripts/default.js" for ::1 at 2017-04-26 10:47:50 -0400

actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:53:in `call'
web-console (3.5.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.5.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (3.5.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (3.5.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.0.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/server.rb:600:in `handle_request'
puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/server.rb:435:in `process_client'
puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/server.rb:299:in `block in run'
puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/default.js"):

actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:53:in `call'
web-console (3.5.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.5.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (3.5.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (3.5.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.0.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/server.rb:600:in `handle_request'
puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/server.rb:435:in `process_client'
puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/server.rb:299:in `block in run'
puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
  Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered collection of C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb [9 times] (3.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (14.5ms)
  Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (1355.1ms)
  Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered collection of C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb [9 times] (3.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (2732.5ms)
```

CMD Error log after I click on 'Destroy' on the index page

```
Processing by ArticlesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"4"}
  Article Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering articles/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered articles/show.html.erb within layouts/application (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 81ms (Views: 57.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/stylesheets/default.css" for ::1 at 2017-04-26 13:12:34 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/default.css"):
Started GET "/javascripts/default.js" for ::1 at 2017-04-26 13:12:34 -0400

actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:53:in `call'
web-console (3.5.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.5.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (3.5.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (3.5.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.0.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/server.rb:600:in `handle_request'
puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/server.rb:435:in `process_client'
puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/server.rb:299:in `block in run'
puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/default.js"):

actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:53:in `call'
web-console (3.5.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.5.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (3.5.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (3.5.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.0.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/server.rb:600:in `handle_request'
puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/server.rb:435:in `process_client'
puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/server.rb:299:in `block in run'
puma (3.8.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
  Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.0ms)
         Rendered collection of C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb [9 times] (3.5ms)
  Rendered collection of C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb [9 times] (3.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (2775.8ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (3170.5ms)
```

rails routes command result:

```
C:\Users\Nick\blog>rails routes
      Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
    articles GET    /articles(.:format)          articles#index
             POST   /articles(.:format)          articles#create
 new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)      articles#new
edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format) articles#edit
     article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#show
             PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
             PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
             DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#destroy
        root GET    /                            welcome#index
```

application.js code

```
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
```

layouts/application.html.erb file code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Scribble</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'default', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'default', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

UPDATE 1:56 PM
Changing some code in the application.js file seems to have alleviated the issue (apparently is was a JS loading error from what I can tell)

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'default', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag 'default', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

FROM ^

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

TO ^

- I shall continue the tutorial and update the post should I run into further issues pertaining to this subject. Thank you all for your help/support so far!!!

Comment: Can you post your `routes.rb` file as well as the the entire error message? For the error message, it would be more helpful if you could copy/paste rather than taking a screenshot.

Comment: It doesn't show the confirmation dialog before?

Comment: This is clear, well-formatted first question - thanks!

Comment: @Brian - posted both of the things you requested. I didn't think to copy/paste the CMD so sorry about the screenshot being not very readable.

Comment: @Seventy-ThreeDavid I've tested your code and it works, the way you're doing it works well, but when you click on delete any record you get a `Completed 200 OK` response, so, I don't see errors, just those related to your assets like `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "...")`, can you show how you're adding them?

Comment: In Rails your assets like js and css files will be loaded "automatically" if you specify the `require_tree .` in your both `application` js and css file, so there's no need to add them as in a "plain" way like `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/default.css">`.

Comment: So, in terms of routes I'm a bit unsure of how they work. I don't remember anywhere in the tutorial where they actually require me, myself to type in a right, but I will post my route list above as well so you can see how they look on my end. Is that what you are referring to me "adding" [the routes] or are you looking for something else?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this error is a result of your javascript not being loaded correctly. Can you show your `application.js` and the way you're including them in your layouts file

Comment: Check this [repo](https://bitbucket.org/hnhm/std), it's implemented as yours, and if you remove the `link` tag within the `app/views/articles/index.html.erb`, you won't see any error on the logs.